# How can I force CQ5.5 to ignore CSS data-uri-schemes?

Tags: css, base64, aem, data-uri

I am trying to include a custom font into css using the data-uri-scheme. CQ5 (I'm using version 5.5) is adding the path from the clientlib directory to the location where the css file with the data-uri-scheme font data is located.

So instead of just ignoring the css property:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomFont';
  src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;...
  ...
}
```

CQ5 does the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomFont';
  src: url(desktop/css/data:application/x-font-woff;...
  ...
}
```

Is this a bug in CQ5.5 or can I add/do something to **prevent the addition of "desktop/css"**?

The result is, I'm getting 404 HTTP status because the font is "not found".

**[UPDATE]**:

The css file is included in the `base.jsp` in the html `<head>` section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="/etc/designs/myproject/clientlib/desktop.css" type="text/css"/ >
```

Location of `base.jsp`:

```
/apps/myproject/pages/base/base.jsp
```

Location of `css.txt`:

```
/etc/designs/myproject/clientlib/desktop/css.txt
```

Comment: Would you mind adding more detail as to exactly how you're including this css in your page?  For example, is this in a css file included by a clientlib?  If so, what is the relevant contents of that css file and what is the snippet of code that's including the clientlibs into your HTML (eg. currentDesign.writeCssIncludes(pageContext);) Is this inline in your cq:Page HTML JSP?  Are you outputting the above in one of your page or component JSPs?  I'm asking in order to duplicate the issue and see if it may be an issue of the link checker or HtmlLibraryManager rewriting the URL for you.

Comment: @JasonDay I have updated my question to answer your questions. Let me know if there is anything else I'm missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, will be fixed with 5.6. Including the individual css file directly (as mentioned) avoids the clientlib rewriting, otherwise I don't know of a workaround inside a clientlib.

The reason is that clientlibs are rewriting the relative paths because the base changes from the individual css file to the concatenated clientlib css. "data:" uris were simply not considered properly here.

Comment: I'm going with this answer since it's also what [Justin Edelson tweeted](https://twitter.com/justinedelson/status/286617359496646656). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a bug.  The CSS is passed through a method that specifically looks for url('{}') in the CSS files concatenated together to create the combined CSS file - CssFileBuilder#resolveUrl(String[], String[], String).  This method doesn't appear to take into account the data scheme, instead it only skips modifying the URL if it has a length of 0, starts with a slash (/) or matches the pattern "^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9+\-.]*://.*" (effectively external links).  My assumption would be that it does this in order to modify relative url('{}') values, but they didn't take into account the data scheme.

I'd recommend opening a Daycare ticket with Adobe to update this method to support the data-uri-scheme.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the detailed analysis. I presumed it would be a bug. If you don't mind me asking do you work at Adobe or have you worked for a client using Day?

Comment: Not at all, I work for a company that uses CQ5 for a few of our websites.

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to this answer, because it's what I presumed would be the case and opening a Daycare ticket is the next step I'd take.

Answer (score 2):

Two strategies for working around CQ5's (usually helpful) link rewrites:

(1) Place the @font-face code in the external .css file(s) that is assembled for you by CQ5.  Instead of using the [<cq:includeClientLib>](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html#%3Ccq%3aincludeClientLib%3E) tag to include it in your HTML, you might find that you have to explicitly code the <link> tag, e.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= currentDesign.getPath() %>/clientlibs/themes/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

(2) Inject the @font-face code with a document.write() call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("@font-face { font-family: 'CustomFont'; src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;
    ...}");
</script>
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the suggestions. I'm aware of both of these solutions. I'd probably go with the first one or use inline css (<style>) to include the fonts. I'm working on a high traffic website where every http-requests counts and I'm hoping to find the solution that lets me use the data-uri-scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Without having checked what caused the misplaced rewriting I assume it was the `Day CQ Link Checker Service`.

You might want to add a `Special Link Prefix` or `Special Link Pattern` to prevent this pattern to be identified as link and being rewritten at all.

So just add your custom linkchecker configuration unter /apps/.. (overlay of corresponding config under libs) with the mentioned changes and you should be fine.

Comment: No, it's not related to the link checker. Clientlibs are rewriting the relative paths because the base changes from the individual css file to the concatenated clientlib css.